# Background image followed by text appearing after 2 Seconds

Tags: android, image

I have a background image(image1 in my drawable folder). I want to make a page in my android app which have this background image and a text "Welcome" should be written in the middle of it after two seconds. Please help me with coding for that.

This is my layout background.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/image1">
```

The related java.

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.background);
    Thread timer = new Thread(){
        public void run (){
            try {
                sleep(2000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally{


            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();
 }

 @Override
 protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    finish();
 }
}
```

I want to understand what should i write inside the finally bracket above to make the text "welcome" appear after 2 seconds. Should i mention welcome as a text view in my background layout.

Comment: I have added the code that i am trying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do a beautiful fade in effect

```
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.background);


    AlphaAnimation alpha = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
                    alpha.setDuration(2000);
                    alpha.setStartOffset(2000);
                    alpha.setFillAfter(true);
                    alpha.start();
                    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcomeTextView)).startAnimation(alpha);
 }
```

And add a textview in your Linear layout with id `welcomeTextView`